# Sequencing records in SQL

Tags: sql

I wish to develop a query that will update the **sequence** column of a table to groups of sequential values based on the **tmr_id** and the **batch_id**. The **Should Be** column reflects the results I am looking for.

So, for all instances of a **batch_id** (34E5, for example), all records with a **tmr_id** of 61114 should have the **sequence** set to 1 with the 61117 records being set to 2 and so on. Often (as shown in the example), I am presented with data out of order. For example, I might get some of batch 34E5, then some 34DE, and then the rest of 34E5. I should never see a situation where there are more than four sequences in a batch group.

I hope I am explaining the situation well enough. The things I have tried have not even been close and I hate to resort to a regular program if an SQL query works.

| tmr_id | trans_id | batch_id | load_time | mix_name | ingredient | sequence | Should Be |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 61114 | 502673 | 34E5 | 11-29-22 7:03 | BEF300-27 | HAND | 0 | 1 |
| 61114 | 502674 | 34E5 | 11-29-22 7:03 | BEF300-27 | GRCORN | 0 | 1 |
| 61114 | 502675 | 34E5 | 11-29-22 7:03 | BEF300-27 | SOYHUL | 0 | 1 |
| 61114 | 502676 | 34E5 | 11-29-22 7:04 | BEF300-27 | SBM | 0 | 1 |
| 61114 | 502677 | 34E5 | 11-29-22 7:04 | BEF300-27 | CITRUS | 0 | 1 |
| 61114 | 502678 | 34E5 | 11-29-22 7:04 | BEF300-27 | CALCAR | 0 | 1 |
| 61114 | 502679 | 34E5 | 11-29-22 7:04 | BEF300-27 | WCS | 0 | 1 |
| 61114 | 502680 | 34E5 | 11-29-22 7:04 | BEF300-27 | CSH | 0 | 1 |
| 61114 | 502681 | 34E5 | 11-29-22 7:04 | BEF300-27 | DDGS | 0 | 1 |
| 61114 | 502682 | 34E5 | 11-29-22 7:04 | BEF300-27 | MOLASS | 0 | 1 |
| 61115 | 502683 | 34DE | 11-29-22 7:23 | HIG100-7 | HAND | 0 | 1 |
| 61116 | 502684 | 34DE | 11-29-22 7:29 | HIG100-7 | HAND | 0 | 1 |
| 61117 | 502685 | 34E5 | 11-29-22 7:50 | BEF300-27 | HAND | 0 | 2 |
| 61117 | 502686 | 34E5 | 11-29-22 7:52 | BEF300-27 | GRCORN | 0 | 2 |
| 61117 | 502687 | 34E5 | 11-29-22 7:53 | BEF300-27 | SOYHUL | 0 | 2 |
| 61117 | 502688 | 34E5 | 11-29-22 7:55 | BEF300-27 | SBM | 0 | 2 |
| 61117 | 502689 | 34E5 | 11-29-22 7:56 | BEF300-27 | CITRUS | 0 | 2 |
| 61117 | 502690 | 34E5 | 11-29-22 7:57 | BEF300-27 | CALCAR | 0 | 2 |
| 61117 | 502691 | 34E5 | 11-29-22 7:58 | BEF300-27 | WCS | 0 | 2 |
| 61117 | 502692 | 34E5 | 11-29-22 8:00 | BEF300-27 | CSH | 0 | 2 |
| 61117 | 502693 | 34E5 | 11-29-22 8:02 | BEF300-27 | DDGS | 0 | 2 |
| 61117 | 502694 | 34E5 | 11-29-22 8:02 | BEF300-27 | MOLASS | 0 | 2 |
| 61118 | 502695 | 34DE | 11-29-22 8:17 | HIG100-7 | HAND | 0 | 1 |
| 61118 | 502696 | 34DE | 11-29-22 8:19 | HIG100-7 | GRCORN | 0 | 1 |
| 61118 | 502697 | 34DE | 11-29-22 8:20 | HIG100-7 | SOYHUL | 0 | 1 |
| 61118 | 502698 | 34DE | 11-29-22 8:22 | HIG100-7 | SBM | 0 | 1 |
| 61118 | 502699 | 34DE | 11-29-22 8:23 | HIG100-7 | CITRUS | 0 | 1 |
| 61118 | 502700 | 34DE | 11-29-22 8:23 | HIG100-7 | BICARB | 0 | 1 |
| 61118 | 502701 | 34DE | 11-29-22 8:25 | HIG100-7 | CALCAR | 0 | 1 |
| 61118 | 502702 | 34DE | 11-29-22 8:26 | HIG100-7 | WCS | 0 | 1 |
| 61118 | 502703 | 34DE | 11-29-22 8:27 | HIG100-7 | CSH | 0 | 1 |
| 61118 | 502704 | 34DE | 11-29-22 8:27 | HIG100-7 | MOLASS | 0 | 1 |
| 61119 | 502705 | 34DE | 11-29-22 8:45 | HIG100-7 | HAND | 0 | 2 |
| 61119 | 502706 | 34DE | 11-29-22 8:47 | HIG100-7 | GRCORN | 0 | 2 |
| 61119 | 502707 | 34DE | 11-29-22 8:48 | HIG100-7 | SOYHUL | 0 | 2 |
| 61119 | 502708 | 34DE | 11-29-22 8:49 | HIG100-7 | SBM | 0 | 2 |
| 61119 | 502709 | 34DE | 11-29-22 8:51 | HIG100-7 | CITRUS | 0 | 2 |
| 61119 | 502710 | 34DE | 11-29-22 8:52 | HIG100-7 | BICARB | 0 | 2 |
| 61119 | 502711 | 34DE | 11-29-22 8:53 | HIG100-7 | CALCAR | 0 | 2 |
| 61119 | 502712 | 34DE | 11-29-22 8:54 | HIG100-7 | WCS | 0 | 2 |
| 61119 | 502713 | 34DE | 11-29-22 8:55 | HIG100-7 | CSH | 0 | 2 |
| 61119 | 502714 | 34DE | 11-29-22 8:55 | HIG100-7 | MOLASS | 0 | 2 |
| 61120 | 502715 | 34DE | 11-29-22 9:07 | HIG100-7 | HAND | 0 | 3 |
| 61120 | 502716 | 34DE | 11-29-22 9:09 | HIG100-7 | GRCORN | 0 | 3 |
| 61120 | 502717 | 34DE | 11-29-22 9:10 | HIG100-7 | SOYHUL | 0 | 3 |
| 61120 | 502718 | 34DE | 11-29-22 9:11 | HIG100-7 | SBM | 0 | 3 |
| 61120 | 502719 | 34DE | 11-29-22 9:12 | HIG100-7 | CITRUS | 0 | 3 |
| 61120 | 502720 | 34DE | 11-29-22 9:13 | HIG100-7 | BICARB | 0 | 3 |
| 61120 | 502721 | 34DE | 11-29-22 9:15 | HIG100-7 | CALCAR | 0 | 3 |
| 61120 | 502722 | 34DE | 11-29-22 9:16 | HIG100-7 | WCS | 0 | 3 |
| 61120 | 502723 | 34DE | 11-29-22 9:17 | HIG100-7 | CSH | 0 | 3 |
| 61120 | 502724 | 34DE | 11-29-22 9:17 | HIG100-7 | MOLASS | 0 | 3 |
| 61121 | 502725 | 34DF | 11-29-22 9:44 | AD200-66 | HAND | 0 | 1 |
| 61121 | 502726 | 34DF | 11-29-22 9:46 | AD200-66 | BICARB | 0 | 1 |
| 61121 | 502727 | 34DF | 11-29-22 9:48 | AD200-66 | CALCAR | 0 | 1 |
| 61121 | 502728 | 34DF | 11-29-22 9:49 | AD200-66 | AMINO | 0 | 1 |
| 61121 | 502729 | 34DF | 11-29-22 9:51 | AD200-66 | MINAD | 0 | 1 |
| 61121 | 502730 | 34DF | 11-29-22 9:51 | AD200-66 | MOLASS | 0 | 1 |
| 61121 | 502731 | 34DF | 11-29-22 9:51 | AD200-66 | ALIMET | 0 | 1 |
| 61122 | 502732 | 34DF | 11-29-22 10:22 | AD200-66 | HAND | 0 | 2 |
| 61122 | 502733 | 34DF | 11-29-22 10:23 | AD200-66 | BICARB | 0 | 2 |
| 61122 | 502734 | 34DF | 11-29-22 10:25 | AD200-66 | CALCAR | 0 | 2 |
| 61122 | 502735 | 34DF | 11-29-22 10:26 | AD200-66 | AMINO | 0 | 2 |
| 61122 | 502736 | 34DF | 11-29-22 10:27 | AD200-66 | MINAD | 0 | 2 |
| 61122 | 502737 | 34DF | 11-29-22 10:29 | AD200-66 | MOLASS | 0 | 2 |
| 61122 | 502738 | 34DF | 11-29-22 10:29 | AD200-66 | ALIMET | 0 | 2 |
| 61123 | 502739 | 34DF | 11-29-22 10:56 | AD200-66 | HAND | 0 | 3 |
| 61123 | 502740 | 34DF | 11-29-22 10:58 | AD200-66 | BICARB | 0 | 3 |
| 61123 | 502741 | 34DF | 11-29-22 10:59 | AD200-66 | CALCAR | 0 | 3 |
| 61123 | 502742 | 34DF | 11-29-22 11:06 | AD200-66 | AMINO | 0 | 3 |
| 61123 | 502743 | 34DF | 11-29-22 11:07 | AD200-66 | MINAD | 0 | 3 |
| 61123 | 502744 | 34DF | 11-29-22 11:07 | AD200-66 | MOLASS | 0 | 3 |
| 61123 | 502745 | 34DF | 11-29-22 11:07 | AD200-66 | ALIMET | 0 | 3 |

Comment: Sample data is great, but perhaps consider a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - emphasis on *minimal*; also please [TAG](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) your RDBMS and its version

Comment: research the RANK() window function

Comment: I had never heard of RANK(), and it looks like exactly what I need.  Thank you.